# They each have two cars/cars

Tags: determiners

**Situation 1**: Jack has a car and Ryan has a car.

a) They each have a car.

b) They each have cars.

Which is correct?

**Situation 2**: Jack has two cars and Ryan has two cars.

c) They each have two cars.

d) They each have cars.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. They each have a car.
2. They each have two cars.  But I'd prefer "They have two cars each."

But you can also say "Jack and Ryan each own cars."  And then the number of cars that Jack has and Ryan has is not determined. It could be one or more than one.

Comment: So *Jack and Ryan each own/have cars* or *They each own/have cars* means we don't know exactly how many cars they each have. Am I right?

Comment: That is correct. You would understand in context, or not care.  If you are saying "Jack and Ryan each own/have cars" You probably are telling someone that both the men are able to travel long distances quickly, so it doesn't matter, in context, how many cars they own.

Answer (score 1):

"They have cars" or "They each have cars" is *grammatical*, but does not specify how many cars each person has—only that each of them has *at least one* car. This is a natural thing to say if the number isn't relevant. For instance, as a response to "Does Jack or Ryan need a ride?"—"No, they have cars."

Technically, "they each have a car" doesn't *rule out* the possibility of (some of) them having more than one car. It would be perfectly fine to say "No, they each have a car" as a response to "Does Jack or Ryan need a ride?" even if Jack has two (or more!) cars. However, if you say "they each have a car" in a context where the number of cars *is* relevant, native speakers will understand you to be saying that they only have one car each. (I can't think of a good example right now.)

You can say "They each have *one* car" if you want to be unambiguous.